# How to export class containing a vector of a private struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I have a Class A ( that I would like to export) which contains a vector of a private struct. When compiling the code I have the warning C4251( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx ). To prevent this warning I did an explicit instantiation. In VS2008 this compiles without any problems but in VS2010 I have following error:

error C2252: an explicit instantiation of a template can only occur at namespace scope

(error C2252:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ds5s2s4(v=vs.100).aspx )

Is there any way to export the class with the vector and keeping the struct private?

```
class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
  public:
    A();
    ~A();

  private:
    struct StructData
    {
      unsigned int b_;
    };

#if defined(WIN32) && !defined(__GNUC__)
    template class __declspec(dllexport) std::allocator<StructData>; // explicit instantiation needed to prevent warning C4251
    template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<StructData, std::allocator<StructData> >; // explicit instantiation needed to prevent warning C4251
#endif
    std::vector<StructData> StructDataVector_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All members of a class need to be exported as well. You can use the [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl_idiom) to hide the implementation of your class.